# While loop that looks at the neighbors of a given node to see if they fit a criteria

Tags: python, arrays, path, grid, nodes

I have an array of X,Y,Z values. X and Y are coordinates, Z is a value calculated from the respective X and Y.

I'm trying to write a code that will start at a given node, looks out the nodes neighbors to see if their z value fits a certain criteria (> then some minimum value but < some maximum value). For each node that passes the criteria, the node will be masked in the array, and then the same process will be performed on that node (in which all neighbors are examined to see if the criteria is met). The while loop ends when reaching another node of known value, or when the edge of the grid is reached.

I've started to code this. I have a neighbors function that creates a sub array of all the nodes that neighbor a given node:

```
def neighbors(arr, x, y):
    return (arr[x-1:x+2,y-1:y+2,:])
```

I'm trying to work through the algorithm in which the logic would be something like this:

begin at starting node

while the node of interest(x,y) is not equal to the ending node(x,y)

find the neighbors of the node, if z1 < startingnode(z) < z2

mask each node that passes then perform the same neighbors search/criteria comparison

The resulting output is an array in which all nodes that satisfy the criteria between the starting node and ending node are masked. The main purpose of the code is to identify all nodes along a path between two points which satisfy the criteria.

I am picturing a while loop with a counter but having difficulty coding it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not to be sarcastic, but the best way is often just to start writing code. We can help with specific problems you encounter, but the general implementation will be up to you. This sort of thing is easiest to start with a small base case and some code that can handle it, then try to scale it up to handle any general case.

Comment: @jcurley fair enough. I suppose i've gotten to a point where I can mask the neighbors for one node, but scaling it up to continue that process is where i'm stuck. I've also achieved a code that can look in just one direction, say just looking right (positive x direction), and i use a counter to increase the node and see if it satisfies, but again still stuck moving to a code that can handle all neighbors and spider out. Sorry for the poorly posed question.